# MVC 5 Can't get Twitter Auth to work anymore

Tags: twitter, katana

This all used to work just fine. It looks like Twitter made yet another change that broke my app.

Twitter used to pass the return URL when calling the ExternalLogin method in my MVC 5 app. It still passes the provider, but there is no return url. Does anyone know how to get the return URL from the Callback URL?

I'm using the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter 4.0 package.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following URL as a valid Callback URL in Twitter's App Settings.

mydomain.com/signin-twitter

Also, it had been a while since I messed with this, so I forgot how all this worked. It seems like the return URL is always null. ExternalLogin gets called first and then redirects to  ExternalLoginCallback.